# Showing different navbar based on devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an ecommerce app with two different devise models `seller` and `buyer`. 
I am not using `subdomains`.So this is how each `urls` looks like

```
http://localhost:3000/buyers/sign_in

http://localhost:3000/sellers/sign_in
```

I am using different devise views for each of these. But I dont want to show the same `navbar` for the `seller` and `buyer`.
How can I check if the user is in `seller  page` or `buyer page` and show a navbar based on that from `application.html.erb`?

I first thought about showing navbar based on the controller but as devise uses same controllers and actions for all models am bit confused here.

I am using different views for buyers and sellers so is it possible to pass a variable or something to application.html.erb from each page(like login,signup) to show the correct navbar?

Comment: I would go for something like <% unless current_page?($path) %> // do something <% end %>

Comment: @KevinEtore Thank you..That should work, but is there any better way other than checking like this..otherwise i have to check every view in devise like so which is cumbersome...It would be better if i can show or hide based on namespace..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate custom controllers for devise and then show navbar based on your controller. In order to this first create your custom controller using the generator within your scope:

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

In your case the scope can by `buyers` or `sellers`. Your new controllers will be create in `app/controllers/[scope]/`.

Replace this line in your `routes.rb` instead of the old one:

```
devise_for :[scope], controllers: {
    sessions: '[scope]/sessions'
}
```

in your case:

```
devise_for :sellers, controllers: {
    sessions: 'sellers/sessions'
}

devise_for :buyers, controllers: {
    sessions: 'buyers/sessions'
}
```

Now you can check for the controller in you view and show navbars accordingly.

Comment: I dont have a model called users. What I have is `sellers` and `buyers`. Both are entirely different devise models. I have done `rails generate devise Seller` and `rails generate devise Buyer` when creating these models. Will this work in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change that. Please see the edited answer.